# Remove nouveau driver (nvidia) without rebooting

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, gpu, modprobe, nouveau

I have a Ubuntu Version here, that is started from USB as a Live version. I do not want to install it on hard disk, because it would be too much for only testing a small thing on Ubuntu.

So I started Ubuntu and installed the nvidia driver (from nvidia) for a GPU (Tesla C2050) with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apg-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

As Ubuntu is started as Live-version, in the beginning, there was the `nouveau` driver activated. I want to deactivate it (maybe through `rmmod` or something. similar), so only the `nvidia` driver is activated and the GPU is using the `nvidia` driver.

How it is possible? What can I do without rebooting the whole system (because all packages installed / removed / changes would be gone)?

I have access to Ubuntu through SSH.

I read that I might be helpful to type the command `sudo update-initramfs -u` but that command generated the output `update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to unload the *nouveau* driver before you can load the *nvidia* driver.
However, the *nouveau* driver is currently in use by the X-server, so it cannot be unloaded yet.
You have to stop the X-server first (but don't just re-start it, as then it will use the *nouveau* driver again).

So in short:

- stop X-server: `sudo service lightdm stop`
- unload the nouveau driver: `sudo rmmod nouveau`
- load the nvidia driver: `sudo modprobe nvidia`
- start the X-server: `sudo service lightdm start`

You might be out-of-luck and the framebuffer for the console is locking the `nouveau` driver as well. In this case I haven't found a way to unload the driver at all...

Comment: I was getting `rmmod: ERROR: Module nouveau is in use` and I found that `echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind` solves the problem. I still have to understand what that command does.

Comment: That command works indeed, but it left me with no console (I was on VT1). No VT1-6 or 7 would work. I had to ssh into the system from the laptop in order to proceed with the other commands. Then I could `rmmod nouveau`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just restarting X?
End session / logout and login again

Comment: I tried it now with `sudo service lightdm restart`. Output says, that `lightdm` stopped and started again. But the command `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12` says, that the GPU is using `nouveau` (`Kernel driver in use: nouveau`)

Comment: Maybe another needed info: I have access to Ubuntu through SSH.